# Passing jQuery object and WebMethod return value to an OnSuccess function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am calling a `WebMethod` from this code:

```
if($(this).attr("checked")) {  
..  
MyWebMethod(variable1, variable2, onSuccessFunction);  
}
```

The `MyWebMethod` returns an integer, and I want to set `$(this).attr("id")` of the jQuery object above to the returned integer. Basically, I'm trying to do the equivalent of an MVC `Ajax.ActionLink...AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetID =...}`  However, I can't figure out how to get both a reference to `$(this)` as well as the returned value.  For example, if I do:

```
MyWebMethod(variable1, variable2, onSuccessFunction($(this)));
```

I can succesfully manipulate the jQuery object, but obviously it doesn't have the return value from the `MyWebMethod`.  Alternatively, the first code block with a method signature of `onSuccessFunction(returnValue)` has the correct return value from `MyWebMethod`, but no concept of the jQuery object I'm looking for.  Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what parameters the onSuccessFunction in your first example is expecting, but something like this will be what you're looking for.

```
if($(this).attr("checked")) {   
  var el = $(this); 
  MyWebMethod(variable1, variable2, function(x, y z) { onSuccessFunction(x, y, z, el); });   
}
```

** Update ** Fixed to avoid a "this" scoping issue.

Comment: I was trying something like this with an anonymous function, and the problem is that $(this) doesn't have the correct reference.  By the time it is called, it ends up referring (I think) to the document as a whole. In any case, not the correct object.

Comment: Check the change that I just made.  It should solve your problem.